# opencv.js throws Uncaught 6576248 from detectMultiScale() in "Face Detection Example"

Tags: javascript, opencv

I am trying to reproduce the opencv.js "Face Detection Example" found on https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/d99/tutorial_js_face_detection.html (using https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/opencv.js).

> TLDR: Why is my local version of the example throwing an Uncaught
> 6576248 exception when its running the same code as the
> https://docs.opencv.org version?

Running this example using the https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/lena.jpg image (you must save it locally before loading it into the example)

```
let src = cv.imread('canvasInput');
let gray = new cv.Mat();
cv.cvtColor(src, gray, cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY, 0);
let faces = new cv.RectVector();
let eyes = new cv.RectVector();
let faceCascade = new cv.CascadeClassifier();
let eyeCascade = new cv.CascadeClassifier();
// load pre-trained classifiers
faceCascade.load('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml');
eyeCascade.load('haarcascade_eye.xml');
// detect faces
let msize = new cv.Size(0, 0);
faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, faces, 1.1, 3, 0, msize, msize); // <----------- Uncaught 6576248 error
for (let i = 0; i < faces.size(); ++i) {
    let roiGray = gray.roi(faces.get(i));
    let roiSrc = src.roi(faces.get(i));
    let point1 = new cv.Point(faces.get(i).x, faces.get(i).y);
    let point2 = new cv.Point(faces.get(i).x + faces.get(i).width,
                              faces.get(i).y + faces.get(i).height);
    cv.rectangle(src, point1, point2, [255, 0, 0, 255]);
    // detect eyes in face ROI
    eyeCascade.detectMultiScale(roiGray, eyes);
    for (let j = 0; j < eyes.size(); ++j) {
        let point1 = new cv.Point(eyes.get(j).x, eyes.get(j).y);
        let point2 = new cv.Point(eyes.get(j).x + eyes.get(j).width,
                                  eyes.get(j).y + eyes.get(j).height);
        cv.rectangle(roiSrc, point1, point2, [0, 0, 255, 255]);
    }
    roiGray.delete(); roiSrc.delete();
}
cv.imshow('canvasOutput', src);
src.delete(); gray.delete(); faceCascade.delete();
eyeCascade.delete(); faces.delete(); eyes.delete();
```

... results in...
[image]

However, when I put this code onto my own test page I get an error message

```
opencv.js:30 Uncaught 6576248
___cxa_throw    @   opencv.js:30
$func2523   @   0161a76e:0xecf45
$func2517   @   0161a76e:0xecc67
$func7868   @   0161a76e:0x4142ce
$func879    @   0161a76e:0x20a8a
$func1174   @   0161a76e:0x2fec3
$dynCall_viiiidiiii @   0161a76e:0x4ee70f
Module.dynCall_viiiidiiii   @   opencv.js:30
dynCall_viiiidiiii_1640 @   VM79763:4
CascadeClassifier$detectMultiScale  @   VM81062:15
proto.<computed>    @   opencv.js:30
```

I have a put the same code into jsfiddle (with some additional console.logs) [and although jsfiddle hides the error further], the problem is when the logic steps into the line reading `faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, faces, 1.1, 3, 0, msize, msize)` - see https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/jy32qr49/

I have also added a delay between the load the the `detectMultiScale` but this doesn't seem to make a difference (https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/jy32qr49/28/).

So why is the https://docs.opencv.org/ version working, but my version's not?